# Error message from iscsiadm while trying to connect to a iscsi drive

Tags: linux, lvm, iscsi

I am trying to access a ISCSI drive on a machine with *IP 1.0.0.13 (hostname store.blue.com)*. The machine in which I am trying to create connection has the *IP 1.0.0.11 (Hostname: loc1.blue.com)*. From *loc1.blue.com* I could discover the iqn but not able to login due to below error.

```
[root@loc1 ~]# iscsiadm -m discovery -t sendtargets -p store.blue.com
1.0.0.13:3260,1 iqn2015-04.com.blue:store.target1
[root@loc1 ~]# iscsiadm -m node -targetname iqn2015-04.com.blue:store.target1 -p 1.0.0.13 -login
iscsiadm: can not recognize operation: 'gin'
```

At first I open ports for ISCSI 3260 & 860 and tried the connection but that didn't help. So I stopped iptables service and disabled firewall on both machines. Still I get the same error.

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax was incorrect. It should have been --targetname. Complete statement is as follows.

```
iscsiadm --mode node --targetname iqn2015-04.com.blue:store.target1 --portal store.blue.com:3260 --login
```

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is wrong - it's not `-login`, it's `-l` or `--login` (note the **two** dashes):

```
# iscsiadm -m node --targetname iqn2015-04.com.blue:store.target1 -p 1.0.0.13 --login
```